# me/friends not returning the friends using facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook application a month before and the Graph API Explorer returns empty array from the query me/friends even there are 5 people allowing the app. It should return the friends using the app isn't it? How can I retrieve the list of friends using the app?

Comment: Perheps its a privacy setting in your facebook account that forbids the app from returning the list?

Comment: And you're sure those 5 people are your friends? And you request the `user_friends`permission?

Comment: yes they are in my friend list and user_friends permission is approved. And the app that I created a year before returns the friends using app if I select version 2.1. So I'm wondering if it is due to the change in userid in old and new app versions. As I can see the userid is different according to app in new version but in older version the userid is the orginal one

Answer (score 0):

You need user_friends permission : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends

Comment: It is a default permission. Isn't it? And it shows under the approved items list in app

Comment: But you still need to request is during login!

Comment: This is not a default permission for newly created applications.
Have a look to this question, it might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m